# Custom NumericUpDown ValueChanged event in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, events, user-controls

Since WPF doesn't contain a `NumericUpDown` control as known from `WinForms`, I implemented my own and take care of upper and lower value bounds as well as other validation.

Now, the `WinForms` `NumericUpDown` held a`ValueChanged` event which would be nice to implement it too. My question is: How can I lift the `TextChangedEvent` of a `TextBox` to my main application? `Delegate`s? Or are there any other preferred ways to implement this?

Comment: Create an event and Subscribe it in Main application

Comment: I think you can customize a `NumericUpDown` from **pure WPF stuff**, `WPF` has a repeatbutton in `System.Windows.Controls.Primitives`, just add more some `TextBox` and validation. You can have a much more elegant numericupdown. Searching for this would help you out with some *samples*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally prefer to use a `delegate` for this purpose, as I can set my own input parameters for it. I would do something like this:

```
public delegate void ValueChanged(object oldValue, object newValue);
```

Using `object` as the data type would allow you to use different numerical types in the `NumericUpDown` control, but then you'd have to cast it to the correct type each time... I'd find this a bit of a pain, so if your control would only use one type, `int` for instance, then you could change your `delegate` to this:

```
public delegate void ValueChanged(int oldValue, int newValue);
```

Then you would need a public property for users of the control to attach handlers:

```
public ValueChanged OnValueChanged { get; set; }
```

Used like so:

```
NumericUpDown.OnValueChanged += NumericUpDown_OnValueChanged;

...

public void NumericUpDown_OnValueChanged(int oldValue, int newValue)
{
    // Do something with the values here
}
```

Of course, that's no good unless we actually call the delegate from inside the control and let's not forget to check for `null` in case no handler has been attached:

```
public int Value
{ 
    get { return theValue; }
    set
    { 
        if (theValue != value)
        {
            int oldValue = theValue;
            theValue = value;
            if (OnValueChanged != null) OnValueChanged(oldValue, theValue);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Value"); // Notify property change
        }
    }
}
```